# Flutter how to get stream information

Tags: flutter

Hy i have created an app in flutter that plays a radio stream of the internet (i own that).
the radio stream is Icecast2 server.

in the online version i can get the stream information and images.
how do i perform this in flutter ?

```
"source":[
         {
            "audio_info":"ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=320;ice-channels=2",
            "bitrate":320,
            "genre":"oldies",
            "ice-bitrate":320,
            "ice-channels":2,
            "ice-samplerate":44100,
            "listener_peak":6,
            "listeners":2,
            
            "server_description":"Very Oldies!",
            "server_name":"My server",
            "server_type":"audio/mpeg",
            "server_url":"127.0.0.1",
            "stream_start":"Sat, 08 Aug 2020 15:16:55 +0200",
            "stream_start_iso8601":"2020-08-08T15:16:55+0200",
            "title":"1957: Johnnie Ray - Yes Tonight, Josephine",
            "dummy":null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StreamBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), very useful flutter widget. It can do the job which you want. The basic format is

- Choose your `Stream` which `yeilds` your data
- Based upon that value, the `StreamBuilder` rebuilds the widget

Comment: Will the stream than also change when the song is changed or can I use a javascript function in flutter

Comment: Yes, you just need to mention that in the `Stream` object what should happen. You can also look for the [List of State Management in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) @AlainSeys